# iOS flutter app not running after updating device to iOS 14.7.1

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-test

After updating my iPhone 11 to iOS version 14.7.1, my flutter app is not launching anymore.
Steps already performed:

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- flutter run

Also,

- uninstalled and reinstalled the app
- restarted the phone

output:

```
(base) Henrys-MacBook-Air:flutter henrycorreia$ flutter run
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter...                             3.2s
Launching lib/main.dart on Henry’s iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: XXXXXXXXXX
Running pod install...                                             25.0s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           208.8s
Installing and launching...                                        58.4s
Error launching application on Henry’s iPhone.
```

==>> flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/henrycorreia/fvm/versions/2.2.3
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (6 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/henr/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Moto E 4 Plus (mobile)  • xxxxxxxxx                • android-arm    • Android 7.1.1 (API 25)
    • Henry’s iPhone (mobile) • xxxxxxxxxxxxxx • ios            • iOS 14.7.1
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131
    

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Is anybody facing the same issue? Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. It seems to be a random issue that happens time to time when updating either the flutter version or iOS...

Here's how I fixed the issue:

==>> you can also get inspired by this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72161

However, what worked for me was very simple as I am using vs code:

- uninstalled the app
- restarted the phone
- open the app using Xcode
- Product -> Clean Build Folder
- Product -> Run

The app will launch correctly, then quit Xcode

After that, I run the app using vs code, and now it works as before.

Answer (score 0):

You have runtime error just before your first screen renders, try putting breakpoint in the first line of the main and debug line by line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my app runs perfectly fine on the simulator iPhone 12 Prox MAx which iOS version 14.5... Yesterday I was running the app just fine then an automatic update run during the night and now I cannot launch the app... In any case, I will try it. Thx